# Как реализовать отслеживание скролла на js?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача, что как только мы доскролливаем до определенного элемента на странице(это будет блок контактов), в навигация меняется активная кнопка(Например, с Home на Contacts). Навигация фиксированная, поэтому кнопка всегда на виду
Как это можно реализовать на чистом js?
Спасибо

Comment: а зачем тут вообще js? как только доскролите до элемента - он появится на экране - всегда так работало

Comment: @Grundy он видимо хочет сделать как при паралаксе, когда скроллишь к элементу, а он анимированно выезжает

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, слишком много вариантов, чего он может хотеть

Comment: @Grundy Вообще это будет навигация со сменной кнопок при скролле

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, не стало понятнее, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: @Grundy Изменил вопрос, глянь пожалуйста

Comment: Добавь пример своей разметки с навигацией и указанием что на что должно поменяться

Comment: @Grundy Нет пока что разметки, мне нужно понять логику. Как вообще можно отслеживать скролл js'ом?

Comment: используй scrollTop - при достижении им определенного значения (нужного отступа сверху страницы) меняй значение кнопки

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, при прокрутке происходит событие scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#your selector"), // here class or id your menu
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+100,
// All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - 100;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
            return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length-1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
        // Set/remove active class
        menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("your active class")
            .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("your active class");
    }
});
```

попробуй этот вариант. должен работать) если я правильно понял вопрос :)

Comment: Спасибо, по-пробую)